# I'm not able to scrape particular title from a website

Tags: python, scrapy, css-selectors

I'm using scrapy to scrape a data from amazon website and when I use selector gadget to show the path which has the title class so it's not extracting that title. Instead when I use {.s-access-title} for a class then it's working. I'm not sure why selector gadget showing the wrong path.

```
import scrapy
from ..items import AmazonsItem


class AmazonSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'amazon_spider'
    start_urls = \['https://www.amazon.in/s?k=agatha+christie+books&crid=3MWRDVZPSKVG0&sprefix=agatha%2Caps%2C269&ref=nb_sb_ss_i_1_6'\]

    def parse(self, response):

        items =  AmazonsItem()

        product_name = response.css('.s-access-title').extract()][1]
```

[amazon page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Py3OY.png)
If you look at this image I'm selecting the title only but it has different class and it's not working when I use this class.
So how do I extract a particular class title from this?
If you have experience with selector gadgets please take a look.
Also If anyone has another idea about how to extract it please tell.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one: The title is in `data-attribute`:

```
import scrapy
from ..items import AmazonsItem

class AmazonSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'amazon_spider'
    start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.in/s?k=agatha+christie+books&crid=3MWRDVZPSKVG0&sprefix=agatha%2Caps%2C269&ref=nb_sb_ss_i_1_6']

    def parse(self, response):
        items =  AmazonsItem()
        products_name = response.css('.s-access-title::attr("data-attribute")').extract()
        for product_name in products_name:
            print(product_name)
        next_page = response.css('li.a-last a::attr(href)').get()
            if next_page is not None:
                next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
                yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

#### output:

```
'Murder on the Orient Express (Poirot)'
'And Then There Were None'
.
.
```

Comment: So why is selector gadget giving me a different class? because I can't find .s-access-title. I want other information as well that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Caz it rendering the data dynamically. Check closely the `response.text`, you will notice the difference.

Comment: attr("data-attribute")...why this?

Comment: also, tell me about how would I know that data is dynamically created? What does dynamic mean here?

Comment: dynamically due the webpage you are observing through inspect window is slightly changed from the original response through some script. Here is original tag: ``` <h2 class="a-size-medium s-inline s-access-title a-text-normal" data-attribute="Appointment with Death (Poirot)" data-max-rows="0">
                  Appointment with Death (Poirot)
                 </h2>``` and rendered tag is: ``` <span class="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal">Appointment with Death (Poirot)</span> ```

Comment: I'm asking how do I get to that tag? because when I do inspect an element then it's giving me a different tag. Suppose I want now author name, price and the image of the book? how do I get that?

Comment: You can check In `parse` function, printout the `response.text`.

Comment: @SiddhantSingh..! Is answer helped you to solve your query?